# How Read Excel Strict Open XML - Python?

Tags: python, xml, dataframe, xlsx

I have a process automatized, and I need read a Excel with Python, like a
pd.read_excel(file), but my archive is a `.xlsx` Strict Open XML and the regular functions to read `dataframe` don't do with strict open `xml`, how do this?

Manually changing to regular `xlsx` is not an option as the file is automatically provided by the process.

I've already tried the regular functions like `read_excel`, `read_xml`, `workbook`, `xlrd`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, openpyxl is not able to read a Strict OpenXML xlsx file generated by an automated process.

I have found out that manually opening the file and saving as xlsx again will make the file readable/writable, so as a workaround I am using the win32com library to convert the file from xlsx to xlsx. This works for the time being, but I’d like to remove this addional step.